# Print integer barcode with zebra in CPCL language

Tags: java, android, printing, barcode, zebra-printers

I have an java app and I'm trying to print code. Everything works fine until my data is an integer,only digits. The printing is made in another function like this :

```
byte[] configLabel = getConfigLabel();
printerConnection.write(configLabel);

private byte[] getConfigLabel() {

    byte[] configLabel = null;

    String str=inputbarcode.getText().toString();
    String str2 = "link";

    StringBuilder print = new StringBuilder("! UTILITIES\r\n");
    print.append("IN-MILLIMETERS\r\n");
    print.append("SETFF 15 2.5\r\n");
    print.append("PRINT\r\n");
    print.append("! 0 180 180 180 1\r\n");
    print.append("CENTER\r\n");
    print.append("BARCODE 128 1 1 50 0 20"+str.toString()+"\r\n");
    print.append("T 0 3 0 80"+str.toString()+"\r\n");
    print.append("T 0 3 0 100"+str2+"\r\n");
    print.append("PRINT\r\n");

    configLabel=String.valueOf(print).getBytes();   

    return configLabel;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet shows missing separator between the barcode and text commands and the actual barcode or text content. Insert one space character at the end of the following strings in your code:

change "BARCODE 128 1 1 50 0 20" to "BARCODE 128 1 1 50 0 20 "

change to "T 0 3 0 80" to "T 0 3 0 80 "

change "T 0 3 0 100" to "T 0 3 0 100 "

Comment: I saw it that day after I asked here. My "y axis" value was to big. Thanks!